# Having some issues attempting to define a variable in a separate class - use to working with one.

Tags: c++, oop, console-application

I am trying to make a Tic-Tac-Toe game using OOP but I am having an issue. When trying to make a playing board with a total of 9 squares and all of them empty as a vector, I do the following.

**Main**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <vector>

int main()
{

    char empty = ' '; //Empty square on playing board
    const int numbOfSquares = 9; //Total amount of squares on board
    std::vector<char> board(numbOfSquares, empty); // The playing board

    return 0;
}
```

In my board class I am trying to do the same thing but it isn't working in the same way.

**Board.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class Board
{
private:
    const char empty = ' '; //Empty square on game board
    const int numbOfSquares = 9; //Number of squares on the board
    std::vector<char> board(numbOfSquares, empty); //The playing board
public:

};
```

An error occurs in saying that 'numbOfSquares' and 'empty' is not a type name. I think I understand this error message but I am not sure on how to resolve it. Could I - overload, is that the term - the board variable in a member function instead?

I am left quite clueless on what to do and would love some help. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<char> board(numbOfSquares, empty);` is not permitted when specifying the list of what your class members are. Instead you should use the constructor initializer list:

```
Board(): board(numbOfSquares, empty)
{
}
```

All members can be initialized this way. For example, your line `const int numbOfSquares = 9;` is a shortcut for writing:

```
Board(): numbOfSquares(9)
{
}
```

However there is no such shortcut for the case where you need to provide constructor arguments in parentheses.

There *is* a shortcut for providing constructor arguments as a braced initializer list, however it's wise to avoid doing this for `vector` as the vector will prefer to treat the contents of the braces as a list of initial values for the vector, rather than as constructor parameters.